# Why does tomcat6 have folders in both /var/lib/ and /usr/share/?

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, installation

I'm new to Linux, and I don't understand why `apt-get install tomcat6` resulted in two `tomcat6` folders, one in `/var/lib/`, the other in `/usr/share/`.  I'm sure there is a good reason for it, but it caused me a few hours confusion with nothing working.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomcat Provides a mechanism where you can run multiple instances that all utilizes some common configuration elements.  You would use the environment variables `CATALINA_HOME` vs `CATALINA_BASE` to configure tomcat(or corresponding properties).  See [this article for an explanation](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1121565).

> "The first properties (catalina.home)
>   points to the location of the common
>   information, while the other property
>   (catalina.base) points to the
>   directory where all the instance
>   specific information are held."

So the [default tomcat6 package in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/tomcat6) has a configuration that is friendly to people who run single instances as well as those who run multiple instances.

You can see that the [tomcat6 package includes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/tomcat6/filelist) both:

- `/usr/share/tomcat6`
- `/var/lib/tomcat6`

If you are only running one instance of tomcat, then you probably want to use the `/var/lib/tomcat6` location.

If by chance you(or other readers) are looking for scripts to automate installing multiple instances of Tomcat on a debian based distro, [this one has worked well](http://code.google.com/p/debian-tomcat-scripts/) for me with some slight modifications.

Comment: By default the init script /etc/init.d/tomcat6 sets:
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat6
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat6

Comment: If we have two identical files/folders in `/usr/share/tomcat6` and `/var/lib/tomcat6`, which takes precedence? For example if you have config files for a Solr instance, let's say.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, the best answer to this question is **Don't use `apt` to install Tomcat**.

`apt` is wonderful for most development tools, but there are exceptions, such as Tomcat and Eclipse.

So just download the `zip` file, expand, and there you are. `logs`, `conf`, `webapps`, `bin`, `lib` and everything else you could need in one place.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib` and `.../share` directories are for (binary) transient files and platform-independent (text, typically) files respectively. See [the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

Comment: But why the duplication?  Why not just /var/lib/tomcat6?

Comment: If a system administrator were to install tomcat6 on a server exporting the application by (say) NFS, in a typical setup, the `/usr` directory would be on the server, and `/var` on each client.